# Deploy dacpac in AzureSQL with AzureDevops

Tags: azure-devops, cicd

I have created a dacpac file from my dev database using SSMS and I want to deploy it in an ASQL environment.

I don't want to build just to deploy the changes of the dacpac file itself to the given asql environment.

Comment: Hi GbrStf345, have you tried to deploy using Azure SQL Database deployment task? Here is a blog [Use Azure DevOps to Deploy an Azure SQL Database](https://medium.com/@sumindaniro/use-azure-devops-to-deploy-an-azure-sql-database-2c79570829cf) with detailed steps for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Azure SQL Database deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task to deploy your DB.

1. Add your DACPAC file in the Azure Repo.
2. Create an Azure Resource Manager service connection. See [Manage service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection) for the detailed info.
3. Add Azure SQL Database deployment task to your YAML or classic release pipeline to deploy your DACPAC file. Take YAML pipeline for example:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '{The ARM service connection created by you}'
    AuthenticationType: 'server'
    ServerName: '{Your target SQL Server name}'
    DatabaseName: '{Your target DB name}'
    SqlUsername: '{SQL Server administrator name}'
    SqlPassword: '{The password of administrator}'
    deployType: 'DacpacTask'
    DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
    DacpacFile: '{Path to your DACPAC file}'
    IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```